# How to show multiple columns under one column at Laravel-excel? But that one column will take take multiple columns area at a time

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-excel

[image]I need to show multiple columns under one column at Laravel-excel. And that one column will take multiple columns area at a time in excel. like - 1st row 1st column name is **"Tissue"** under that column I need to show ***"Super Gold,Pink,White Butterfly,White Panpata"***. And *"Tissue"* column will take four rows in excel file and under "tissue" column show that four names of tissue. and 1st row 2nd column is **"Facial Tissue   "**. It takes one row cause under **"Facial Tissue"** has **"120 Sheet X 2 Ply"** column.
Again 1st row 3rd column is **"Napkin Tissue"** and it contains three columns . Cause I need to show **" 13" x 13",100 Sht/Pkt, Economy Pkt,"** these in 3 columns.

```
        $excel_dynamic_data_array = array();
        $index=0;
        $excel_dynamic_data_array_sur_name = array();
        foreach ($productGroup as $gKey => $group )
        {
            $col_[$gKey] = false;
            foreach($all_product as $pkey => $product)
            {
                if($productGroup[$gKey]["id"] == $product->product_group_id)
                {
                    $col_[$gKey] = true;
                }
            }
            if($col_[$gKey])
            {
                $product_Names_with_keys = $productGroup[$gKey]["t_product"].$productGroup[$gKey]['gorupName'];

                $excel_dynamic_data_array[$index][] = $productGroup[$gKey]['gorupName'];
                $index++;
            }
        }

        $item  = $excel_dynamic_data_array;    //------------- Get type of  Product name

        $item_name = implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
                                                return ($entry[key($entry)]);
                                            }, $item));
        
        foreach($all_product as $key => $product)
        {
            if(empty($product->product_sur_name))
            { echo ( "N/A ");
            }else{
                $excel_dynamic_data_array_sur_name[$index][] =$product->product_sur_name;
                $index++;
            }
        }
        $sur_names = $excel_dynamic_data_array_sur_name;  //------------- Get Product names
        $sur_name = implode(', ', array_map(function ($entry) {
                            return ($entry[key($entry)]);
                        }, $sur_names));
            if ($customer_type == 2)
            {
                $excel_data_attribute_array_column = array(
                    array_merge(
                        array('SL','Order No','Order Date','Challan No','Challan Date','Bill No','Party Name','Area'),explode(',',$item_name),array('Total')
                    )
                );
                $excel_data_attribute_array_2nd_column = array(
                    array_merge(
                        array('','','','','','','',''),explode(',',$sur_name)
                    )
                );
            }
        }
        $total_final_array = array_merge($excel_data_attribute,$excel_data_attribute_array,$excel_data_attribute_array_column,$excel_data_attribute_array_2nd_column);
    }
    return collect($total_final_array);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is to use export using View and using `colspan` attributes.

[Laravel-Excel Export from view](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/from-view.html)

```html
  <td colspan=4>Tissues over four cells</td>
```

Comment: It's not simple blade file.  So I can't write like that.

Comment: I don't understand what prevent you exactly from doing it

Comment: I follow this formate - https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/ .
So I don't understant laravel excel from view formate.

Comment: I tried different way. I can't solve this problem.